# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}$, find values of p

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I have a sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}$ and $p>1$. Use integral tests and determine which values of $p$ can the partial sum, $s_5$ estimates true sum of $s$ to within $10^{-6}$ error. So this is a question about errors. It says using $s_5$, so error formula is $error \leq \int_{5}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}$. So I calculate the sum and I can get p?  Here I need $10^{-6}$ maximum error, so I equal
$10^{-6} \leq \int_{5}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}$. And finally it's get $p = 3.246$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What exactly is your question? You seem to have solved the problem yourself. Are you asking if you did it correctly? We'll be happy to help once we understand exactly what the question is ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes, but I don't know it's wrong or correct. Can people check it?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}\qquad \text{and} \qquad I_p=\int_{5}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}\,dn$$The integral is easy to compute since
$$J=\int \frac{n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}\,dn=\frac 13\int \frac{3n^2}{(1+n^3)^p}\,dn=\frac 13\int \frac{dx}{(1+x)^p}\,dx=\frac 13\int \frac{dy}{y^p}$$that is to say
$$I_p=\frac{3^{1-2 p} \,14^{1-p}}{p-1}$$ So, making the problem more general,you want to know $p$ such that
$$10^{-k} \leq \frac{3^{1-2 p} \,14^{1-p}}{p-1}$$ or
$$(p-1)\,126^{p-1} \geq 3 \times 10^k$$ Rewrite it as
$$\big[(p-1)\log(126)\big] e^{\big[(p-1)\log(126)\big]} \geq 3 \log(126)\times 10^k$$ and the solution of the equation is given is terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$(p-1)\log(126)=W\big[ 3 \log(126)\times 10^k \big]\implies $$ $$\color{blue}{p=1+\frac{W\big[ 3 \log(126)\times 10^k \big] }{\log(126)}}$$ Since that argument is large, you can evaluate it using
$$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

For $k=6$, this will give $p\sim 3.866$.